# cannot resolve `velocity-react` because of lodash dependencies not being found

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've been hacking away at this one for a while. I have `lodash` and `velocity-react` installed. `velocity-react` depends on `lodash@3.10.0`.

When I build my app with webpack 2, I get a number of errors like this:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash/object/extend'
```

However, if I change the version to `3.10.0`, it spawns a lot of different errors for different packages, saying things like:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash/isObject'
```

It seems like the problem is that these libraries are depending on different major versions of lodash. What's the way to fix this?

EDIT: I found a workaround, but it certainly seems a bit off. I can add the following to my `resolve.alias` in order to patch it:

```
'lodash/object/omit': 'lodash/omit',
'lodash/object/extend': 'lodash/extend',
'lodash/lang/isObject': 'lodash/isObject',
'lodash/lang/isEqual': 'lodash/isEqual',
'lodash/collection/forEach': 'lodash/forEach',
'lodash/collection/each': 'lodash/each',
'lodash/collection/pluck': 'lodash/map',
'lodash/object/keys': 'lodash/keys',
```

But why do I need to do this? Surely there must be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day with your workaround. Still WTF, but at least it works now...

Comment: You should add that edit as an answer and then accept it. This is really helpful, thank you!